# Move to the sea shore/a seashore/the seaside/the beach/the coast/the sea

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-choice

If I'm talking about moving to a city by the sea, which of the following is the correct choice ?

I want to move to the

- sea shore
- a seashore
- the seaside
- the beach
- the coast
- the sea

Comment: The fifth one: move to the coast.

Comment: I would find _the seaside_ acceptable too (we speak of 'a seaside town'). _The seashore_ and _the beach_ sound as though you are planning to camp out on the sands!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fifth one: move to the coast. But I would find the seaside acceptable too (we speak of 'a seaside town'). The *seashore* and the *beach* sound as though you are planning to camp out on the sands! And the *sea* suggests you are going to become a sailor on a ship.

Comment: converted comments